# weirdest bug ever - int definition causes sigsegv. stack overflow?

Tags: c++, bsp

I'm using the BSPlib and when adding a simple definition of "int i" on the function running on multiple threads (along with many other) I get a message like "Process 2 caught SIGNAL 11 Segmantation fault ". it's important to note that I checked alot and without it I don't get the segmentation fault and with it I get it almost all the time.
how could int definition cause it? is there a stack overflow I might have caused?
thanks.

```
int P;
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    /** sequentail - process 0 */
    P=bsp_nprocs(); /// maximum number of process avialble (must do that on sequential part ,need for bsp begin)
    bsp_begin(P);
    char* str1;
    char* str2;
    int n;
    int** table;
    int thread=bsp_pid();
    int num_threads=bsp_nprocs();
    if(thread == 0)
    {
        ifstream file1(argv[1]);
        ifstream file2(argv[2]);
        // check if the strings are the same size RDBG
        string string1((istreambuf_iterator<char>(file1)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        string string2((istreambuf_iterator<char>(file2)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        n=string1.length();
        str1= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
        str2= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
        strcpy(str1,string1.c_str());
        strcpy(str2,string2.c_str());
    }
    if (thread!=0)
    {
        str1= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
        str2= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
    }
    bsp_push_reg(&n,SZINT);
    bsp_sync();
    bsp_get(0,&n,0,&n,SZINT);
    bsp_sync();
    if (thread==0)
    {
        table=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n+1));
        for (int i=0; i<n+1; i++)
            table[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n+1));
    }
    bsp_push_reg(str1,SZCHAR*(n+1));
    bsp_push_reg(str2,SZCHAR*(n+1));
    bsp_push_reg(table,n*n*SZINT);
    bsp_sync();
    if (thread==0)
    {
        for(int t=1; t<num_threads; t++)
            for (int k=0; k<=n; k++)
            {
                bsp_put(t,str1+k,str1,k*SZCHAR,SZCHAR);
                bsp_put(t,str2+k,str2,k*SZCHAR,SZCHAR);
            }
    }
    bsp_sync();
    cout << thread << "!!!" << str1 << ";" << str2 << endl;
    int i;
    bsp_sync();
    bsp_pop_reg(table);
    bsp_pop_reg(str2);
    bsp_pop_reg(str1);
    bsp_pop_reg(&n);
    bsp_sync();
    free(str1);
    free(str2);
    bsp_sync();
    bsp_end();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please share some code sample for us to look at.

Comment: This is probably not the weirdest bug ever.

Comment: I don't think the int definition is the cause of your problem, it just shows you there's an error somewhere else in your code. The definition moves other variables in memory and f.e. some pointer bug that erroneously changed "variable_i_just_need_once" now changes "dont_change_this_i_need_it_everywhere".

Comment: More `C with classes` code mascaraing as C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration/initialization of the table variable is incorrect. You are initializing it as an array of arrays (i.e. as n+1 distinct memory blocks), whereas you are telling bsplib that it is a a contiguous memory block of n*n ints. You either need to change your allocation or the registration.

As a consequence, bsplib overwrites memory that isn't initialized at all.

Answer (score 1):

In the vast majority of cases where a semmingly innocuous change causes or fixes a problem, you have what's known as a Heisenbug. In that case, it's not the actual change that's the root cause, the change is just a catalyst to cause the true bug to surface.

I'm not entirely certain how BSPlib does its threads but it appears to me that the `n` value is not initialised for the case where `thread` is non-zero.

In other words, the value is set to the length of `string1` only for `thread == 0` yet it is used to `malloc` space for `thread !=0`, said space being dependent on whatever rubbish happened to be on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string string1((istreambuf_iterator<char>(file1)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    string string2((istreambuf_iterator<char>(file2)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    n=string1.length();
    str1= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
    str2= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
    strcpy(str1,string1.c_str());
    strcpy(str2,string2.c_str());
```

What happens when string2 is longer than string1? Is this ever the case? You are using `malloc` to allocate the size of `string1` in `str2`. If `string2` is longer than `string1`, you will buffer overflow, probably clobbering all kinds of stuff in memory.

Should you be doing `n1 = string1.length(); n2 = string2.length();`?

Comment: the program is designed only for equal strings